# How to place Xib on google map as Marker instead of google map marker icon

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-markers

I am doing a project where I am adding the marker on to the google map but I wants to add the custom marker of Xib like  I want to add my custom view onto the map instead of marker.icon default of google map

I have made a uiview where I will download the image from the and then wants to place that UIView on the Map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For **custom view as marker**, you can use `iconView` of `GMSMarker`.

```
- (UIView*) iconView
```

> Marker view to render. If left nil, falls back to the icon property
>   instead. Supports animation of all animatable properties of UIView,
>   except frame and center. Changing these properties or their
>   corresponding CALayer version, including position, is not supported.
>   Note that the view behaves as if clipsToBounds is set to YES,
>   regardless of its actual value.

For more refer to: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker.html#aa16a89bd5187e64e71c57c31c150a44d

Just set your custom view as the `iconView` of your marker.

```
 let marker = GMSMarker()
 marker.iconView = UIView() //Your custom view here
```

Comment: Thanks @PGDev for your help(y)